# mail() function cannot work with two email filters?

Tags: php, email, explode, filter-var

I have this function to send an email. It was working fine up until I added to it an additional check to the input email (besides filter_var()) coming from a form where I check for specific domain names and I reject them accordingly.

I cannot understand why isn't working now.

I've added to the top of my file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It just won't show me any error message nor send the email.

The part that fills the parameter ($correo) hasn't changed:

```
<?php
function enviarMails($correo) {
    $miMensaje = "bláh, bláh";
    if (!filter_var($_POST['emailRemitente'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Oops! Email incorrecto";
    } else {
            $rejectedDomains = array('midominio.org', 'midominio.com');
            $emailParts = explode('@',$_POST['emailRemitente']);
            if (in_array(strtolower($emailParts[1]), $rejectedDomains)) {
                echo "<br>Oops! email incorrecto";
            } else{     
                    $emailRemitente = $_POST['emailRemitente'];
                    $nombreRemitente = $_POST['nombreRemitente'];
                    $para   = $correo;
                    $asunto = 'ATENCION';
                    $mensaje = $miMensaje;
                    $headers = 'From: '.$nombreRemitente.' '.'<'.$emailRemitente.'>'."\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                    //mando mail a los usuarios
                    $envioUsuarios = mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers);
                        if($envioUsuarios) { 
                            echo '<br><span class="ok">Mensaje enviado a '.$correo.'</span><br>'; 
                        } else {
                        echo'<br><span class="error">No se mandó mail a '.$correo.'</span><br>'; }
                }
    }
}
```

The operative part here is the filters lines:

```
...
FIRST FILTER:
if (!filter_var($_POST['emailRemitente'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Oops! Email incorrecto";
    } else {
            $rejectedDomains = array('midominio.org', 'midominio.com');
SECOND FILTER:
            $emailParts = explode('@',$_POST['emailRemitente']);
            if (in_array(strtolower($emailParts[1]), $rejectedDomains)) {
                echo "<br>Oops! email incorrecto";
            } else{     
...
```

NOTE: As english isn't my native language, I couldn't come up with a better title for this post. If the title isn't descriptive enough, please, feel free to make it better and clearer.

Comment: Where's the part where you add the filters? (Also, the title looks OK)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've edited the post in order to point to the two filters part in a more specific way. :)

Comment: That `mail()` returns `true` only means the mail server accepted the mail but that doesn't mean the mail server has or will send it. The PHP code looks fine to me. Check the mail server logfiles.